# Magento2: How to add script .js to block

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want add script with reviews to custom_block in magento 2.

```
<span id="__ceneo-reviews-5404f405-e31c-4e74-9b51-0ebeee8bcd2d"></span>
<br/>
<small>
    <a href="https://www.ceneo.pl/26306-0a" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">&raquo; przeczytaj wszystkie opinie</a>
</small>

<script>
    (function (d,t){
    var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://':'http://')+'ssl.ceneo.pl/shops/rw.js?accountGuid=5404f405-e31c-4e74-9b51-0ebeee8bcd2d';
    s.async=true;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    }(document,'script'));
</script>
```

after save, I see only this content in html.
[image] Looks .js do not work here. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I hope, you may call that block in your custom phtml file right If so you can keep html element in cms block and keep JS snippet in your custom phtml file.

Something like below way,

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
    (function (d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://':'http://')+'ssl.ceneo.pl/shops/rw.js?accountGuid=5404f405-e31c-4e74-9b51-0ebeee8bcd2d';s.async=true;s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);}(document,'script'));
</script>
```